# Difference between crc32() implementations of <linux/crc32.h> and <zlib.h> in C

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, checksum, crc32

I am calling two functions on my `char* s = "pratik"` as:

User code:

```
#include <zlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *s = "pratik";
    printf("%x\n",crc32(0x80000000, s, strlen(s)));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
66fa3c99

Kernel code:

```
#include <linux/crc32.h>

int main()
{
    char *s = "pratik";

    u32 checksum = crc32(0x80000000, s, strlen(s));
    printk("\nChecksum --> %x", checksum);

    return checksum;
}
```

Output:

Checksum --> d7389d3a

Why are the values of the checksums on the same strings different?

Comment: `strlen(6)`... are you sure?

Comment: Besides the possible errors in your code, keep in mind that CRC is actually a *family* of algorithms, parameterized by several options (first of all the digest size - always 32 bit in your case -, but also the polynomial used, the bits endianness, the initialization value, plus some extra bits manipulations that can be performed at various stages of the algorithm). Given that the kernel implementation is born to compute CRC values for network packets I wouldn't be surprised that it has reversed bit endianness. Some interesting info about CRC: http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt.

Comment: While the generator polynomials appear to be the same (Linux references [ITU V.42](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.42-200203-I/en), which is identical to [what zlib uses](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c), there are [little-endian and big-endian versions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/crc32.h) of `crc32` in `linux/crc32.h`. Can you try calling `crc32_be` instead?

Comment: @mindriot When I run crc32_be(s), it prints B131FB25, which still doesn't match the user call and crc32_le(s) prints the same value as crc32(s) of the kernel program.

Comment: Maybe you also need to change the endianness of the seed value (replace `0x80000000` by `0x00000080` maybe)? To ensure that the seed is not causing the problem, I suggest you set it to 0 and compare the two `crc32` versions again.

Comment: 360D86BA and 6b9ca574 are the values returned by the linux/crc32.h and zlib.h version respectively, and hence, still not working :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears that someone was disturbed by the fact that the standard Ethernet (PKZIP, ITU V.42 etc. etc.) CRC-32 does a pre- and post-exclusive-or with `0xffffffff`. So the version in the Linux kernel leaves that out, and expects the application to do that. Go figure.

Anyway, you can get the same result as the (correct) zlib `crc32()`, using the (non-standard) Linux `crc32()` instead, thusly:

```
crc_final = crc32(crc_initial ^ 0xffffffff, buf, len) ^ 0xffffffff;
```

In fact, that exact same code would allow you to duplicate the Linux `crc32()` using the zlib `crc32()` as well.

Comment: Stroke of genius! Thank you, really. Been on this since ages!